# Obtaining rustdoc for particular function or trait

Tags: rust, rustdoc

Is it possible to obtain a rustdoc fragment for particular function or trait from a programming library written in Rust like it's done in Javadoc tooling? Is there some tool for this?

Comment: Why not use regex?

Comment: I'd highly encourage you to explain what it is you are trying to accomplish. It's absolutely **possible** to do this - generate the documentation, open it up in an editor or web browser, then copy and paste the desired documentation.

Comment: @Shepmaster And I'd highly encourage you to explain that in Netbeans or Eclipse you can obtain context help for current Java class entirely automatically

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean; I have a feeling that the intended tone in your comment (sarcasm?) isn't translating well in text form. Are you trying to generate documentation from inside an IDE? Are you trying to automatically insert skeleton documentation comments based on the code present? It certainly seems like one answer to the question as currently phrased is to run `cargo doc --open` and look at the result.

Comment: @Shepmaster It seems to me that my wish to obtain context help (e.g. in IDE like RustDT) for current code entity is quite natural and does not require much explanation.